# preg_match_all Get links from <a href="" with Class

Tags: preg-match-all

I was in tourble on my simple project...

I'm trying to grab all the links from tag a href tag, but my problem is that the links also have other attributes, that is class.

**This the source structure:**

```
<a class="coolCard project-card " href="http://www.aabbcc.com/post//tank-farm-good-be" id="2568">
```

**What i tried so far is:**

```
preg_match_all('/<a\s*class=\"coolCard \s[^\>]*\"\s*href=([\'"])(.*?)\\1/is', $wordString, $links);
```

For result, i want to get the link http://www.aabbcc.com/post//tank-farm-good-be

Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra space in your regex:

```
preg_match_all('/<a\s*class=\"coolCard \s[^\>]*\"\s*href=([\'"])(.*?)\\1/is', $wordString, $links);
//                             here __^
```

Juste remove it:

```
preg_match_all('/<a\s*class=\"coolCard\s[^\>]*\"\s*href=([\'"])(.*?)\\1/is', $wordString, $links);
```

.

```
$wordString = '<a class="coolCard project-card " href="http://www.aabbcc.com/post//tank-farm-good-be" id="2568">';
preg_match_all('/<a\s*class=\"coolCard\s[^\>]*\"\s*href=([\'"])(.*?)\\1/is', $wordString, $links);
print_r($links);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <a class="coolCard project-card " href="http://www.aabbcc.com/post//tank-farm-good-be"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => "
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.aabbcc.com/post//tank-farm-good-be
        )

)
```

Comment: @AdhyKunKun: Strange, it is working fine for me, see my edit